# How to show popup on page leave with React router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I want to show user a popup when they try to leave the page. The popup will have to buttons - on to save content and leave and another to just leave without saving.

I'm using `router 3.2.1`

I tried to make use of `routeLeaveHook` functionallity, and it works to open the dialog.

But the problem I'm facing right now is I'm not sure how to handle two functions which should run on button clicks? Should I push to history in them to navigate to the clicked page? How can I get `nextLocation` there? Or should I use `routeLeaveHook` somehow? Or is there another way to do all of it?

Thank you for your help!

```
       class MyDialog extends React.Component {

            componentDidMount(): void {
                const { route,  routeLeaveHook} = this.props;
                routeLeaveHook(route, this.routerWillLeave);
            }

            routerWillLeave = (nextLocation: string): any => {

                if (dataToSave) {
                    ...open dialog
                }
                return false;
            }

    render () {

            <div open={isOpen}>
             ...some content
              <button onClick={this.saveAndLeave}>
               Save and leave
              </button>
              <button onClick={this.leave}>
               Leave
             </button>
            </div>
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
Right now I think I should move my `routerWillLeave` logic to container of Dialog instead of putting it inside the dialog

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/myw173jyq8
hey check this code sandbox for navigation away using react router prompt with custom dialogue.

Comment: I don't think Prompt available in router 3?